# PHP web-service multiple data passing?

Tags: php, web-services, dataset, resultset

I am currently trying to receive a result set from Access database using a PHP web-service. The code I current have is a script for functions/web-method:

```
require_once "lib/nusoap.php";

class food 
{
 public function getFood() 
 {
    $MyDb = realpath("WEBSERVICES/db/Database.mdb");
    $connect = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO.");
    $connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=$MyDb";
    $connect->Open($connStr);

    $sql = "select all the stuff needed the query works fine";

    $result = $connect->Execute($sql);

    $resultslist = (
    $Routecode = $result->Fields['RouteCode']->Value &
    $Route = $result->Fields['Route']->Value &
    $StationName = $result->Fields['StationName']->Value &
    $Platform = $result->Fields['Platform']->Value &
    $ArrivalTime = $result->Fields['ArrivalTime']->Value &
    $Departure = $result->Fields['Departure']->Value &
    $Status = $result->Fields['Status']->Value
    );

    return $resultslist;
    }
 }

 $server = new soap_server();
 $server->configureWSDL("foodservice", "http://the site");

 $server->register("food.getFood",
 array("type" => "xsd:string"),
 array("return" => "xsd:string"),
 "http:// the site /food",
 "http://the site /food#getFood",
 "rpc",
 "encoded",
 "Get food by type");

 @$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

and the second script that calls the function:

```
require_once "lib/nusoap.php";
$client = new nusoap_client("MY.WSDL.FILE", true);

$result = $client->call("food.getFood");
echo $result;
```

I can get a single piece of data to display but if i try multiple as shown in the $resultlist then it shows a "0" if i rearange the list i sometimes get a single data for one of the items from the lists, strange I know. So my question is, how do I pass all data over, similar to VB.net dataset/datatable etc?

Comment: How is this `vb.net` related at all? It is not, please remove tags that are not relevant

Comment: ` $resultslist =` looks weird

Comment: If i had only one item of data in the $resultslist it works fine but trying to get the 7 pieces of data at once is a different matter :(